# How to know when creating set or frozenset

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I am reading Building Skills in Python (*Lott*) and trying out some examples. I see that the `set(iterable)` function creates both a mutable set and an immutable frozenset. How do I know if I am creating a set or a frozenset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is simply incorrect. The [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) built-in returns a set, not a frozenset. [`frozenset()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) returns a frozenset. A set and a frozenset are both [set types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#types-set), however they are *distinct* set types.

[The Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html) can always be useful for clarification on things like this, there's an entire [list of built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

---

<sup>Excerpt from the book Building Skills in Python (Lott) noted by OP in a comment, emphasis mine.</sup>

> A set **value** is created by using the `set()` **or** `frozenset()` factory
>   functions. These can be applied to any iterable container, which includes any sequence, the keys of a dict,
>   or even a file.

The author here is using "set value" to describe a value of set *type*, and is thus not indicating that `set()` and `frozenset()` do the same thing - they produce values of distinct set types, namely sets and frozensets.